# Calculate the frequency of words in python

Tags: python, arrays, string, list, replace

I have to calculate the frequency of each word which is there in text file if it matches with the word which is there in an array but i am getting this error **TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'**

```
import string
from collections import Counter
from array import *
cnt=Counter()
word =[ ]
word_count = [ ]
new_array =['CC','CD','DT','EX','FW','IN','JJ','JJR','JJS','LS','MD','NN','NNS','NNP','NNPS','PDT',
                       'POS','PRP','PRP','RB','RBR','RBS','RP','SYM','TO','UH','VB','VBD','VBZ','WDT','WP','WP','WRB']
file = open('output.txt', 'rU')
for line in file:
      new_line = line.replace("_"," ")
      words = new_line.split()
      word.append(words)

[(w, word.count(w)) for w in set(word) if w in new_array]
```

Comment: I do not know if it is supposed to be like this, but in your `new_array` list there are duplicate entries...Removed duplicate entries: `new_array=['CC','CD','DT','EX','FW','IN','JJ','JJR','JJS','LS','MD','NN','NNS','NNP','NNPS','PDT','POS','PRP','RB','RBR','RBS','RP','SYM','TO','UH','VB','VBD','VBZ','WDT','WP','WRB']`

Answer (score 1):

When you do `word.append(words)`, you are appending a list to a list, there by making a list of lists.
As a list is not hashable, a list of lists cannot be converted into a set and you were getting that error.

I think you were intending to do `word += words` instead.